# no kernel loaded

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, windows-8, gnu

I installed Ubuntu on my laptop, which already had Windows 8.1 installed. Then I uninstalled Ubuntu but when I restart my laptop it boots to GRUB recovery:

```
GNU GRUB version 1.97 beta 4
[Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB
lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible
device/file completions.]
```

When I type `boot` it says `no kernel loaded`. So what should I do? I can't repair my Windows 8.1; if I do then it will revert back to Windows 8 and I would lose my data. I have a bootable USB for Ubuntu 15.04 that I can successfully boot from. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to repair your windows 8.1 boot config. This is done by loading up win 8.1 recovery/install cd and selecting the repair my computer option from the menu choose troubleshoot, then command prompt enter these commands in command prompt.

```
bootrec /FixMbr
bootrec /FixBoot
bootrec /ScanOs
bootrec /RebuildBcd
```

Press Enter after each command and wait for each operation to finish
Remove the cd and reboot.

Comment: if i do it, i may have lose my data and win 8.1,
is there not any option without repairing windows?

Comment: i don't have windows cd, i have built in registered windows!

Comment: You should check if the manufacturer can provide recovery software you need to follow tye steps above to rebuild the boot records for 8.1 it can only really be done from a win 8.1 recovery disk.

Comment: i've done as you mentioned above, but it is not working!